# I would like to create report of users with multi factor turned on and those that dont have it

Tags: powershell

I would like to run a report that lists amount of users that have multi factor tuned on and those that dont - if I could output it to a spreadsheet that would be real helpful.

Comment: Users on which system? To know at least that, quoting, "would be real helpful".

Comment: Office 365 Azure AD.

Answer (score 2):

This should produce the desired report:

```
Get-MsolUser -all | select UserPrincipalName, @{N = "MFA Status"; E = { if($_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -ne $null) { $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State } else { "Disabled"}}}
```

You can export the results in CSV format by piping the output into `Export-Csv`.

Of course, before running the command you have to connect to Office 365 using the `Connect-MsolService` command; and first of all, you have to install the MsOnline PowerShell module if you already don't have it installed.